# Selenium C# & Visual Studio 2015 getting "Obtaining the runtime type of transparent proxy" issue

Tags: c#, selenium, runtime

I've seen that some other professionals facing this issue as well, but nowhere the real solution is given. Selenium page factory / when initialize IWebElement through [FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "yourID")] driver is unable to interact with these elements. Trying to debug it and receiving "**Obtaining the runtime type of transparent proxy is not supported in this context**" on the line where interactions with element start. Not really what it is, I did automation in the past only in Java. 
System info:

```
    Visual Studio 2015           version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
    .Net Framework               version 4.6.01055
    Selenium.Support             version 3.0.0
    Selenium.WebDriver           version 3.0.0
    NUnit                        version 3.5.0
```

Please help if anybody faced and resolved that issue.